# Extract results from Breusch Godfrey Test in a plm function

Tags: r, regression, panel-data

I need to create a table in which i I have the id of the panel data regressions in the rows, and the statistics of the model in the columns. I am trying to extract the results (Statistics, df, p-value) from the Breusch Godfrey test to insert into the table. One remark is that I am running many regressions with the same command. I tried doing

```
GodfreyallModelsResultsF <- lapply(allModelsList, function(x) 
  bgtest(plm(x, data=data, model="within")))

GodfreyallModelsResultsF2 <- as.data.frame(
  matrix(unlist(GodfreyallModelsResultsF,use.names=TRUE), 
         nrow=length(unlist(GodfreyallModelsResultsF[1]))))

GodfreyallModelsResultsF <- t(GodfreyallModelsResultsF)
colnames(GodfreyallModelsResultsF) <- c("BPTest","df","name","Pvalue","code")
```

But it didn't work. One last remark is that I was able to use this code to successfully extract from Breusch Pagan test.
Could someone help me in the B-G issue?

Comment: is it possible to get a reproducible data sample with `dput(head(your_data))` please?

Comment: I understand that it would be a lot easier, but unfortunately I can't provide it due to a confidentiality agreement within the place I work. Sorry

Answer (score -1):

Here is the way of extracting `p-value`:

```
model <- plm(x, data = data, model = "within")
as.numeric(pbgtest(model)[4])
```